# How to send/read java ByteBuffer (websocket) from javascript client onmessage function

Tags: javascript, java, websocket

Server code in java:

```
@OnMessage
public void onMessage(Session session, ByteBuffer message) {
    if (session.isOpen()) {
        String msg = new String(message.array());
        System.out.println("Message from " + session.getId() + ": " + msg);
        try {
           session.getBasicRemote().sendBinary(ByteBuffer.wrap("I have got the message".getBytes()));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.toString());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Session is not open");
    }
}
```

Client code in Javascript:

```
    webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.10.1:2525/myChat/chat");
    webSocket.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
    webSocket.onopen = function(event) {
        updateOutput("Connected!");
        connectBtn.disabled = true;
        sendBtn.disabled = false;
    };

    webSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
        updateOutput(event.data);
    };
```

Note: 
  Server code works fine when I use it with Web GL client as it is send Binary data.
  Javascript client works fine when I read String data in Server end 
  (from java code):

```
@OnMessage
public void onMessage(Session session, String message) {}
```

Thanks in advice for any comments.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to the issue.

I have used ByteBuffer.js library to send/read data of ByteBuffer type in JavaScript:

`webSocket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";`

In the function onmessage for reading data:

```
var d = event.data;
console.log(d.toString());
```

In the function send for sending data:

```
var bb = dcodeIO.ByteBuffer.wrap(text);
webSocket.send(bb.toArrayBiffer());
```